# How are first-person perspective videos shot?

Tags: film-techniques, cinematography

I want to know what kind of cameras are typically used to shoot first-person perspective videos or movies and how they are shot?

Here's an example. The song [Smack my bitch up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smack_My_Bitch_Up) by The Prodigy.

Here's the [Video Link](http://vimeo.com/44561183)

In this video the main character is shown drinking a glass of vodka in a bar. And the viewers feel like the camera is kept either in the face of the character or inside the mouth.

Here's an another [example](http://vimeo.com/6540668).

Comment: Why would there be a "typical" camera for this kind of shot? Technology advances and what was hard to do years ago is now far easier and in better quality.

Answer (score 4):

DSLR cameras can be used to take POV shots. Commonly DSLR cameras are mounted on to a helmet camera rig to really bring the POV to life. The helmet rig with the DSLR Cam is worn by the actor and it directs the audience gaze down to the hands showing the objects being touched and everyday actions being carried out.

[image: DSLR mounted to helmet camera rig for POV shots]

Answer (score -5):

Those were probably made with a GoPro camera.

Not with the 1997 video, admittedly. But almost definitely a compact video camera of some kind mounted to the person.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter @BeingJudas - but GoPro was first sold cameras in 2004 and Smack My Bitch Up was from 1997. The answer is therefore not complete as such techniques were in use before.

Comment: Here's [a behind the scenes of the TV show "Peep Show" (a UK sitcom)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5lPWegq11o) that is entirely filmed in POV style. The camera they use is a "normal" one, so absolutely not "a compact video camera".

Comment: Using smaller cameras was never crucial in making POV videos. There are a lot of films and TV series using this filmmaking techniques, which were shot with wide angle lenses